# bridge or route wlan traffic to eth

Tags: networking, routing, bridge, connection-sharing

Have been trying to make a laptop share its wireless connection via ethernet to other devices, but am getting nowhere.
First tried bridging, but soon found out bridging wireless interfaces is not that trivial.
The most logical way seemed to be routing traffic via iptables rules (eg as [described here](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/share-your-laptops-wireless-internet-with-ethernet-devices-0130528/)), but with this option the device to-be-connected via eth didn't show any connections.
As a last try, tried sharing connection over eth as per NetworkManager's configuration option, but still no joy. Debian's official manual was simply confusing.

So far have tried succeeding on 3 different host devices - 'pure' debian, ubuntu, and raspberry pi running on raspbian. Anyone who has done this recently and could shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

The laptop should be set up to allow forwarding and to `masquerade` packets to the internet, and the clients should be set up to use the laptop as gateway.

Forwarding may involve flipping the kernel flag `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to `1` from its default `0`, and perhaps make this happen at reboot by appropriate editing of `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Though these details may be different for different distributions.

Forwarding also involves ensuring that the `FORWARD` chain of the `filter` table allows the traffic (e.g. an ACCEPT policy, or specific rules).

Masquerading involves adding such a `POSTROUTING` chain rule of the `nat` table.